# jQuery Ajax call to HTTP Handler (.ashx)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, httphandler

I have an HTTP Handler that sends an image to the client (during a postback):

```
    public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Byte[] pic = GetPhoto(Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["userID"]));

        if (pic != null)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(pic, 0, pic.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
            context.Response.WriteFile("/AllImages/DefaultPicture_large.png");
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use this handler to send the image to the client with a jQuery ajax request?

A few questions:
                       1) How to convert the image to JSON ?
2) If it's not possible to convert the image to JSON, which format can I use to send the image to the client?

Tnx a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just looking to display it on the page? Why not just write an img tag with the src pointing to your handler?

Something like:

```
var img_url = '/myImageHandler.ashx?userDI=' + some_user_id;
$("#displayArea").append($("<img src='" + img_url + "' alt='user image' />"));
```

Answer (score 3):

**1)** To send the image as JSON, you need to convert it to base64 encoded string:

```
 string imageString = Convert.ToBase64String(pic);
 return imageString;
```

**2)** However, not all browsers (IE < 8) support the data-uri scheme which you need to use to display those base64 encoded images.

The best approach would be to write an `img` tag with the `src` pointing to httpHandler.